# Ofbiz16.11 Job scheduling using GUI

Tags: ofbiz

I have Created a service and trying to schedule using GUI (**https://localhost:8443/webtools/control/scheduleJob**). It scheduled correctly but at run time showing following error :

> 2019-04-11 14:53:52,794 |OFBiz-JobQueue-1     |SafeObjectInputStream
>   |W| ************************Incompatible class:
>   sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo. Please see OFBIZ-10837.  Report to dev ML
>   if you use OFBiz without changes. Else add you class into
>   UtilObject::getObjectException
>
> Error running script at location
>   [component://webtools/groovyScripts/service/JobDetails.groovy]:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: Incompatible class:
>   sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo

I am using ofbiz16.11

May be JobDetails.groovy have some issue

Answer (score 1):

You also asked on OFBiz user ML and that's the best way to go.

But please also subscribe to the user ML for such questions and then use your email client. See why here http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

You will get a better support, it's more fair to share with everybody  and people can answer you on the ML rather than directly to you.
The wider the audience the better the answers you might get

Thanks